# How print the filepath with its hyperlink to open it using javamail

Tags: java, hyperlink, jakarta-mail

How to print the File path in a java mail with its hyperlink to open the file.

Consider I have an validated xml file in specific path in my server Directory  (ex: D:\order\order.xml)

1. I already written code to send mail using java mail API ,now I need to print the Full path in the java mail with the hyperlink of the file path.
2. That File path should get displayed in my mail and when i click the File path then it should automatically go to the path and fetch the file for further modification

can any one guide me to achieve this?

This is a piece of my java code.

```
MimeMessage message = new 
MimeMessage(session);                                   
m_toterr=validatexml.Total_err;
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));   
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to1));
message.setSubject("RE : CAR Validation Report at : 
"+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
String htmlBody = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Page Title</title>"
.
.
.
    FileUtils.moveFile(source,fail);

    System.out.println("\nFile moved to QCFAILED Directory...!!!");
    logger.info("\nFile moved to QCFAILED Directory...!!!");
   //File Path
    System.out.println("FFFFound    
    path:"+source.getAbsolutePath());
    logger.info("\nFile moved to QC Failure Directory...!!!");
```

-----code ends
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a valid URI of the form

```
file://D:\order\order.xml
```

This points out that the location is a local file.
Note that this will not work if the file is located on a different machine. In that case you will want to expose that file with a directory listing or something similar to make it available.

You can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme for more information.

Comment: A file: URL isn't going to work for this; the file is on a different machine than the machine that will be used to read the email message.  You need the file to be accessible through an http: URL on your server.  How to do that depends a lot on what kind of server software you're using.